# Match, Copy, and Add Values between Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Looking to match values of column 1&2 of the same row on sheet2 to values of column 1&2 of the same row on sheet1. Then, copy entire row of sheet1 match onto next blank row of sheet3 + copy value of column 3+4 of same row sheet2 onto end of pasted row on sheet3.

```
IF Sheet2 Row First&Last (column1&2) Name match Sheet1 Row First&Last (column1&2)
THEN
Copy Sheet1 Row, paste to Sheet3 @ next blank Row. Copy Sheet2 Row column 3+4 @ end of previously pasted Row on Sheet3
```

Here is what I have so far, this doesn’t do anything right now but I have pieced it together from a few working macros to try and accomplish what I’m after. I haven’t been able to find examples of “Copy Sheet2 Row column 3+4 @ end of previously pasted Row on Sheet3” so I just have a description on the line where I think the code should go.

```
Sub Match_Copy_AddValues()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, s3 As Worksheet
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
     
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet 'List with dump data'
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet 2") 'List of names to match, and additional information to be added'
    Set s3 = Sheets("Sheet 3") 'Worksheet to copy rows of matched names'
    Dim r As Long 'Current Row being matched?'
     
    On Error GoTo fìn
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet 2")
    With Sheets("Sheet 1")
    r = Application.Max(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row) 'Defines # of rows to apply If/Then to?'
    For r = Application.Sum(v) To 2 Step -1 'Each time If/Then is ran, reduce # of rows to apply If/Then to?'
    If CBool(Application.CountIfs(ws2.Columns(1), .Cells(r, 1).Value, ws2.Columns(2), .Cells(r, 2).Value)) Then _
    .Rows(r).EntireRow.Copy s3.Cells(K, 1) 'Compares value in (r)row column 1 and 2, sheet2, to sheet1(activesheet), if equal THEN copies entire (r)row onto sheet3 @ next empty row'
    'take (r)row of match and copy value of column 3 and 4 sheet2 onto the end of previously pasted row on sheet3'
    Next r
    End With
    fìn:
     
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit help Luke

Answer (score 0):

The code below doesn't do everything just the way your attempt suggests but I wrote it in very plain language so that you will surely be able to teak it back into your track where it has transgressed to where it shouldn't go.

```
Sub MatchNameAndInfo()
    ' 02 Aug 2017

    Dim WsInput As Worksheet
    Dim WsInfo As Worksheet
    Dim WsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' Last row of WsInput
    Dim R As Long                               ' WsInput/WsInfo row counter
    Dim Tmp1 As String, Tmp2 As String          ' Clm 1 and Clm2 Input values
    Dim Cmp1 As String, Cmp2 As String          ' Clm 1 and Clm2 Info values

    Set WsInput = Worksheets("Krang (Input)")
    Set WsInfo = Worksheets("Krang (Info)")
    Set WsOutput = Worksheets("Krang (Output)")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WsInput
        Rl = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Rl < 2 Then Exit Sub

        For R = 2 To Rl                         ' define each input row in turn
            Tmp1 = Trim(.Cells(R, 1).Value)
            Tmp2 = Trim(.Cells(R, 2).Value)
            Cmp1 = Trim(WsInfo.Cells(R, 1).Value)
            Cmp2 = Trim(WsInfo.Cells(R, 2).Value)
            If StrComp(Tmp1 & Tmp2, Cmp1 & Cmp2, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                TransferData R, WsInfo, WsOutput
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function TransferData(R As Long, _
                              WsInfo As Worksheet, _
                              WsOut As Worksheet)
    ' 02 Aug 2017

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rt As Long                              ' target row

    With WsInfo
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 4))
    End With

    With WsOut
        Rt = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
        Rng.Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rt, 1)
    End With
End Function
```